# Constraint output for ML algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, combinatorics

When we have to select `1` output out of `N` outputs. We often have an ML architecture such as

`L1` x `L2` ... x `N`

Where, in the end, we do a softmax to make the output layer as a probability of selecting a given output.

My question is, what happens if we want to select `2`, or, more generally, `k` out of `N` outcomes. Is there any literature available on this?

I have a few ideas, but I'm trying not to reinvent the wheel.

Finally. What to do if we want to break down a value of `1` into `k` outputs from `N` possible outputs.

Comment: Could you please give a more concrete example? Without one, it is hard to follow what you’re describing.

Comment: It sounds like instead of a soft relaxation of argmax (which is softmax), he is looking for a soft relaxation of argtop-k.